# How to make links open within webview or open by default browser depending on domain name?

Tags: android

I have WebView in which I want to open links belong to domain www.example.org in webview while all other links (if clicked) open by the default browser outside of my application.

I tried to use public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)  but it does not work properly.

Here is the code that does not work:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
               public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                   try {
                   URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                   if (urlObj.getHost().equals("192.168.1.34")) {
                       view.loadUrl(url);
                       return true;
                   } else {
                       view.loadUrl(url);
                       return false;
                     }
                   } catch (Exception e) {

                   }
               }
}
```

In both cases ( return true and return false) the URL is handled by my application.

Comment: This code really gives you no clue what the different behaviors are when returning a different boolean value because you are calling view.loadUrl() in both cases, thus producing the same result.  If you removed that line from both statements you would see that return false still loads the url in the WebView...and return true does nothing (you must manually do something).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Once you create and attach a `WebViewClient` to your `WebView`, you have overridden the default behavior where Android will allow the ActivityManager to pass the URL to the browser (this only occurs when no client is set on the view), see [the docs on the method for more](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29).

Once you have attached a `WebViewClient`, returning false form `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` passes the url to the `WebView`, while returning true tells the `WebView` to do nothing...because your application will take care of it.  Unfortunately, neither of those paths leads to letting Android pass the URL to the browser.  Something like this should solve your issue:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
      URL urlObj = new URL(url);
      if( TextUtils.equals(urlObj.getHost(),"192.168.1.34") ) {
        //Allow the WebView in your application to do its thing
        return false;
      } else {
        //Pass it to the system, doesn't match your domain
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        //Tell the WebView you took care of it.
        return true;
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I know that seems a little counterintuitive as you would expect `return false;` to completely circumvent the `WebView`, but this is not the case once you are using a custom `WebViewClient`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the code but unfortunately this does not work either. I tried your code, external browser loads the url (www.example.org)  as soon as I start the application.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with the if statement that chooses the path.  I have updated the example now that you have posted code using the same if-else check that you did (we're both assuming that statement evaluates your URLs correctly).

Comment: Hi it still does not work. Again external browser handles the url no matter what the opposite of my code. It seems google docs on this

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html  is either wrong or misleading. Esp note in that doc they say: "Returning true says that the method has handled the URL and the event should not propagate (in which case, an Intent would be created that's handled by the Browser application)."

Comment: Can you post the rest of your Activity code?  If the browser handles your clicks regardless...it sounds like your WebViewClient implementation is not properly attached to the WebView...

Comment: Thanks Wireless Designs, that worked. Note that "request" in your code should be Uri.parse(url) instead.

Comment: My answer for newbies and those who got confused by android documentation. Please check. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26059756/609782

Answer (score 5):

If you can't be bothered to explain what "does not work properly" means, we can't be bothered to give you much specific help.

Use `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`. Examine the supplied URL. If it is one you want to keep in the `WebView`, call `loadUrl()` on the `WebView` with the URL and return `true`. Otherwise, return `false` and let Android handle it normally.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your activity

```
@Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("192.168.1.34")) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    Log.d("URL => ", url);    // load URL in webview
                    return false;
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent); // Pass it to the system, doesn't match your domain 
                return true;
            }
```