# Hyperlinks within the same page in android webview to load within application page

Tags: android, webview

I have created an android app that loads a web page. The app loads page and on clicking any hyper-links on web page, it loads inside the browser of phone. How to avoid this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android WebView click open within WebView not a default browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986788/android-webview-click-open-within-webview-not-a-default-browser), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7308904/link-should-be-open-in-same-web-view-in-android), or even [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907045/how-to-make-links-open-within-webview-or-open-by-default-browser-depending-on-do)... and probably lots more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to create a custom implementation of the WebViewClient for your WebView. Inside of your WebView Activity, add the following

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, when you initialize your WebView, add the following line

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```